# Unable to take screenshot in Iframe

Tags: angular, iframe, screenshot, html2canvas

I am having an issue with taking screenshots in the `Iframe` using `html2canvas`.

Here I am able to take screenshots other than the `Iframe` element.

I have created an example [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/html2canvas-sat?file=src/app/app.component.html) demo here.

Please help me, what I am doing wrong here. What is the other way to take screenshots in Iframe?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to screenshot an iframe with a different origin (like in your stackblitz) - it's not possible with `html2canvas` because of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy.

Also see their limitations http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html#limitations

To get a screenshot from different document you'll need something `node.js` or any other server-side programming language based, for example
`puppeteer` (got it from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56544058/11579919) answer)

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function run() {
    let browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    let page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.scrapehero.com/');
    await page.screenshot({ path: './image.jpg', type: 'jpeg' });
    await page.close();
    await browser.close();
}

run();
```

If you want to screenshot an iframe with the same origin - I'm sure it will work with very basic code from their documentation

```
html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
});
```

Comment: Hi, I had seen this answer already. I don't know how to implement this in angular. If it is possible, can you please implement and share the stackblitz link? Note: I want to take a screenshot from different origin.