# I am unable to take screenshot of iframe

Tags: jquery, css, codeigniter

I am  unable to take screenshot of my frame

```
$(function() {     
    $(document).on("click","#btnSave",function(){
        html2canvas($("#widget"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                theCanvas = canvas;
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                $("#img-out").append(canvas);    
            }
        });    
}); 
    });
```

The first image is with the QR code[image: This is with OR code]

[image: And the second image is when i am taking screenshot the QR code disappears]

Comment: how are you taking screenshot?

Comment: On click of save button

Comment: Seems like duplicate ticket https://stackoverflow.com/q/52869639/1483629

Comment: With content loaded from a different origin, this would only be possible if that content was CORS-enabled to begin with.

Comment: Any other possible way to do it??because it is on the same domain@misorude

Comment: I added header of CORS but it is still not working  i added this on my constructor                                                                                      header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:https://www.localhost/2019/tv/');
           header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
           header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 604800');
           header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
           header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST");@misorude

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This

      <div id="capture" style="padding: 10px; background: #f5da55">
        <h4 style="color: #000; ">Hello world!</h4>
      </div>
      <div id="click">Click To Capture</div>
```

script code

```
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.5.0-beta4/html2canvas.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
           $('#click').click(function(){
             html2canvas(document.querySelector("#capture")).then(canvas => {
           document.body.appendChild(canvas)
          });
         });
        </script>
```

Comment: First Try to create new project module and only this code and then compare your code what is actual Problem